# pynverse inversefunc : how to get invertible function when the original function have multiple variables?

Tags: python

I have a function like this

```
def calculation_function(x,prefecture_name):
    # here, I omit the computation
return y
```

And the relationship between x and y is like this:

```
    y = calculation_function(x,'A')
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ESXt.png)

Now, I want to calculate the invertible function. I got some values of y and the corresponding prefecture_name and I want to estimate the value of x.
My codes is :

```
from pynverse import inversefunc

invcube = inversefunc(calculation_function)
aaa = invcube(0.05778898865521945,'A')
```

But the result showed

```
"calculation_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'prefecture_name'"
```

How can I pass the 'prefecture_name' value to invcube? 
Thank you vary much!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to omit the second argument in the inversion process, since it's called `name`. You can do it with `functools.partial` or simple lambda:

```
inversefunc(partial(calculation_function, prefecture_name="a"))
inversefunc(lambda x: calculation_function(x,"a"))
```